# Professional builders. This is what they left. How do I fix?

Tags: doors, framing

We had a company frame, drywall a new bathroom.  Although there are some minor issues, one I found well after the fact is the bypass bathroom closet door installation.  Walls are pretty plumb, doors are plumb.  Doors line up on the left perfectly.  However, slide them to the right and it goes from touching on the bottom to almost an inch gap on the top. I have no idea how this could be.  That wall isn't that far out of plumb.  I'm not sure how to fix without it looking terrible! Any suggestions?

[image: gap at top]

[image: gap at bottom]

Comment: If they are professionals, quite sure they would come back and fix it.

Comment: I think the wall holding the track was not leveled if this is an overhung door and both side walls are plumb. You can check it easily use a level.

Comment: Track wall is level.  In fact both doors are perfectly plumb when moved to the left wall, only the right wall is problematic.

Comment: I did ask about them fixing.  They really didn't show much interest, maybe by next year if things get slower. Maybe not.

Comment: I hope you haven't paid them their full amount.  If so, you might mention you'll be forced to leave a negative review, with pictures, on Yelp.

Comment: You say all is pretty well plumb. Obviously something isn't. Which is it? Wall, door, tracking, floor?

Comment: Need to recheck everything to see what is the problem.  Everything should be plumb and level and square, not almost or close.  You might be able to adjust the door hangers a bit, but will probably just transfer the problem to the other end.

Comment: Either the door or the wall is out of plumb, remember a small amount of out of plumb translates over a large distance 1 degree is .12 inches per foot if that helps.  Always use the largest level you can fit if you  using a 4 foot level it look level but compared to a 6 ft it will not be.

Comment: The track that the door runs on can have a high or low spot that will make the door show that kind of issue, If everything is plumb with the walls, lake a level, place it on the edge of the door and move the door slowly from one end of the track to another, stopping in places and check for plumb on the door.